# matlab diagonal code

Tags: matlab

tesconf is 3x3 matrix;

```
tes_avg = (diag(tesconf)./sum(tesconf,2));
```

example that the result of tes_avg is given [0.345;0.3423;0.483]

However, i wish to get average result of this 3 values, how should i change the code above?Please advise...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply `avg = mean(tes_avg);` (or directly `tes_avg = mean(diag(tesconf)./sum(tesconf,2));`).